# Using nth-child to alternate colors in a table except for selected groups of TRs

Tags: html, css

I have a table in `HTML` which I am applying a `CSS` class using `nth-child` to give the rows alternating colors.  However there are some sets of rows I would like to be the same color.  If I put a tbody around these sets of rows, is there a way to specify in `CSS` to make rows in that tbody the same color, and then continue alternating colors?  The alternative is to manually set row colors which seems like a bit too much of a hack.

So for example:

```
<table class="alternate-row-colors">
  <tr>
     <td>Blah blah blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>Same color as below</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Same color as above</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Continue alternating colors of rows</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you upload the code that you have for we can fiddle around?

Comment: Not from your description...`nth-of` doesn't work that way. If you have some code we might be able to tale a look.

Comment: Why not add class to these `tr` instead of breaking HTML?

Comment: To be honest, This question has shown very little Google or Bing research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can find is to break each section into separate `tbody` elements and apply the alternate class to the ones with the required styling.

The rows would not **completely** alternate as the number of rows would, I presume not be known in advance...but it's close.

```css
.alternate-row-colors tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #bada55;
}
.alternate-row-colors tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <TBODY class="alternate-row-colors">
    <TR>
      <TD>Monday</TD>
      <TD>09/11/2000</TD>
      <TD>Kelsey</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Tuesday</TD>
      <TD>09/12/2000</TD>
      <TD>Lindsey</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Wednesday</TD>
      <TD>09/13/2000</TD>
      <TD>Randy</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Thursday</TD>
      <TD>09/14/2000</TD>
      <TD>Susan</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Friday</TD>
      <TD>09/15/2000</TD>
      <TD>Randy</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Saturday</TD>
      <TD>09/16/2000</TD>
      <TD>Lindsey</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Sunday</TD>
      <TD>09/17/2000</TD>
      <TD>Susan</TD>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
      <TD>Monday</TD>
      <TD>09/18/2000</TD>
      <TD>Melody</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Tuesday</TD>
      <TD>09/19/2000</TD>
      <TD>Christiane</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Wednesday</TD>
      <TD>09/20/2000</TD>
      <TD>Symphony</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Thursday</TD>
      <TD>09/21/2000</TD>
      <TD>Starflower</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Friday</TD>
      <TD>09/22/2000</TD>
      <TD>Miko</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Saturday</TD>
      <TD>09/23/2000</TD>
      <TD>Cleo</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Sunday</TD>
      <TD>09/24/2000</TD>
      <TD>Alyx</TD>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
  <TBODY class="alternate-row-colors">
    <TR>
      <TD>Monday</TD>
      <TD>09/25/2000</TD>
      <TD>Dancing Star</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Tuesday</TD>
      <TD>09/26/2000</TD>
      <TD>Dawn</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Wednesday</TD>
      <TD>09/27/2000</TD>
      <TD>Josh</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Thursday</TD>
      <TD>09/28/2000</TD>
      <TD>Ryan</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Friday</TD>
      <TD>09/29/2000</TD>
      <TD>Mary Kay</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Saturday</TD>
      <TD>09/30/2000</TD>
      <TD>Hallie</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>Sunday</TD>
      <TD>10/01/2000</TD>
      <TD>Paul</TD>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the closest solution to the problem.  I had to create various css types to handle the various options to display each tbody correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use the `<tbody>` type of element to hold the 'same colour' blocks then using the `nth-child` element is easy using the direct selector `>` thus:

```
.alternate-row-colors  > tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #A4D1FF;
}
.alternate-row-colors > tr:nth-child(odd) { 
background-color: #EAF4FF;
}
```

This will then only effect the `tr` elements which are **direct** descendent of the class.

Comment: Tested on jsfiddle and it doesn't work, because jsfiddle wrap all `tr` element inside a `tbody` element generating 3 tbody elements. I don't know if this behavior is just from jsfiddle or if it is common to other browsers

Comment: Then he can wrap the ones he wants to change in some other  element such as a div perhaps or another class?

Comment: Besides (from what i can tell) the tbody element isint supposed to be used this way. Since its supposed to signify the body of the content in the table,

Answer (score 0):

How about

CSS

```
.alternate-row-colors > tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .2);
}

.alternate-row-colors > tr:nth-child(even), .alternate-row-colors-solid {
background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .4);
}
```

Or set as a third color

```
.alternate-row-colors-solid {
    background-color: blue;
    }
```

And if you want to group than create a table in a table i suspect is the easiest method.

HTML

```
<table class="alternate-row-colors">
<tr>
<td>Zebra coloring</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Zebra coloring</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="alternate-row-colors-solid">
<tr>
<td>Same color</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>same color</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>same color</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Zebra coloring</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Zebra coloring</td>
</tr>
</table>

.alternate-row-colors .alternate-row-colors-solid > tr {
    background-color: orange;
    }
```

And than set the second table and its childs with width and height of 100% remove padding, margin and so on so they dont look like a sub table.